# AngularJS and Angular 1 both same

Tags: angularjs

What is the difference among angularJS, angular 1 and angular 2 ?
Can you please tell the difference among them?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(application_platform)):

> "...AngularJS" referring to the 1.X versions and "Angular" without the
>   "JS" referring to versions 2 and up. .."

Full Quote:

> Originally, the rewrite of AngularJS was called "Angular 2" by the
>   team, but this led to confusion among developers. To clarify, the team
>   announced that separate terms should be used for each framework with
>   "AngularJS" referring to the 1.X versions and "Angular" without the
>   "JS" referring to versions 2 and up.

Answer (score 0):

**AngularJS:**

AngularJS (commonly referred to as "Angular " or "Angular.js ") is a complete JavaScript-based
open-source front-end web application framework mainly maintained by Google and by a community of individuals and corporations to address many of the challenges encountered in developing single-page applications .
Angular 2 has been released after Angular 1.

To get the difference between them,please visit the following link of Angularjs.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html

And more about angularjs please visit...

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info